# Unable to install dlib from Dockerfile on Raspberry Pi

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi, dlib, raspberry-pi4

I'm trying to install dlib in Dockerfile on a Raspberry Pi 4.

Outside of Docker, I am able to install dlib on the Pi by running

```
pip3 install --upgrade dlib
```

But when I try to do it in a Dockerfile as follows:

```py
FROM resin/raspberry-pi-python:3
COPY raspi.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/raspi.list
COPY sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list
COPY pip.conf /root/.pip/pip.conf 
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get install -y --fix-missing \
    build-essential \
    cmake \
    libopenblas-dev \
    liblapack-dev \
    libatlas-base-dev \
    libx11-dev \
    libgtk-3-dev \
    gfortran \
    git \
    wget \
    curl \
    graphicsmagick \
    libgraphicsmagick1-dev \
    libatlas-dev \
    libavcodec-dev \
    libavformat-dev \
    libboost-all-dev \
    libgtk2.0-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    liblapack-dev \
    libswscale-dev \
    pkg-config \
    python3-dev \
    zip \
    && apt-get clean && rm -rf /tmp/* /var/tmp/*
RUN python3 -m ensurepip --upgrade

RUN pip3 install --upgrade dlib
```

I get errors when I try to build the docker image:

> Step 9/12 : RUN pip3 install --upgrade dlib  ---> Running in
>   bf5fa67b254d Looking in indexes:
>   http://mirrors.aliyun.com/pypi/simple/ Collecting dlib   Downloading
>   http://mirrors.aliyun.com/pypi/packages/05/57/e8a8caa3c89a27f80bc78da39c423e2553f482a3705adc619176a3a24b36/dlib-19.17.0.tar.gz
>   (3.4MB) Installing collected packages: dlib   Running setup.py install
>   for dlib: started
>       Running setup.py install for dlib: finished with status 'error'
>       Complete output from command /usr/local/bin/python3.6 -u -c "import setuptools,
>   tokenize;**file**='/tmp/pip-install-sak074zk/dlib/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',
>   '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install
>   --record /tmp/pip-record-7yn41l3u/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
>       running install
>       running build
>       running build_py
>       package init file 'dlib/**init**.py' not found (or not a regular file)
>       running build_ext
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "", line 1, in 
>         File "/tmp/pip-install-sak074zk/dlib/setup.py", line 261, in 
>           'Topic :: Software Development',
>         File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/**init**.py", line
>   129, in setup
>           return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
>         File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
>           dist.run_commands()
>         File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
>           self.run_command(cmd)
>         File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
>           cmd_obj.run()
>         File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py",
>   line 61, in run
>           return orig.install.run(self)
>         File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/distutils/command/install.py", line 545, in run
>           self.run_command('build')
>         File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
>           self.distribution.run_command(command)
>         File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
>           cmd_obj.run()
>         File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
>           self.run_command(cmd_name)
>         File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
>           self.distribution.run_command(command)
>         File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
>           cmd_obj.run()
>         File "/tmp/pip-install-sak074zk/dlib/setup.py", line 129, in run
>           cmake_version = self.get_cmake_version()
>         File "/tmp/pip-install-sak074zk/dlib/setup.py", line 120, in get_cmake_version
>           out = subprocess.check_output(['cmake', '--version'])
>         File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 336, in check_output
>           **kwargs).stdout
>         File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 418, in run
>           output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
>       subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', '--version']' died with .
>
> ---
>
> Command "/usr/local/bin/python3.6 -u -c "import setuptools,
>   tokenize;**file**='/tmp/pip-install-sak074zk/dlib/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',
>   '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install
>   --record /tmp/pip-record-7yn41l3u/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-sak074zk/dlib/ You are using pip version 10.0.1,
>   however version 19.2.3 is available. You should consider upgrading via
>   the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command. The command '/bin/sh -c pip3
>   install --upgrade dlib' returned a non-zero code: 1

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it to work by changing the base image to
FROM raspbian/stretch

```
# get base image
FROM raspbian/stretch

RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get install -y --fix-missing \
    build-essential \
    cmake \
    libopenblas-dev \
    libblas-dev \
    liblapack-dev \
    libatlas-base-dev \
    libx11-dev \
    libgtk-3-dev \
    gfortran \
    git \
    wget \
    curl \
    graphicsmagick \
    libgraphicsmagick1-dev \
    libavcodec-dev \
    libavformat-dev \
    libboost-all-dev \
    libgtk2.0-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    liblapack-dev \
    libswscale-dev \
    pkg-config \
    python3-dev \
    python3-numpy \
    python3-pip \
    software-properties-common \
    zip \
    && apt-get clean && rm -rf /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

RUN pip3 install setuptools --upgrade
RUN pip3 install cython --upgrade


#Install dlib
RUN cd ~ && \
    mkdir -p dlib && \
    git clone -b 'v19.9' --single-branch https://github.com/davisking/dlib.git dlib/ && \
    cd  dlib/ && \
    python3 setup.py install --yes
```